# Jquery justguage graphs not generating properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, justgage

Hi friends I am using Jquery plugin JUSTGUAGE to generated the svg graphs.

I have the following code in html

**HTML**

```
      <div>
        <div>
    <div id="g1" class="graph">
                        </div>
         </div>         
                                </div>
```

Initially one graph in there in the page afer receiving AJax response I need to update the sameone instead of that a new graph is created and two graphs are there in the div like it keeps on multiplying.

**AJAX CODE**

```
 $function{ 
 //code
.done(
            function(data) {
                var cal = 0;
                   cal= data.cal
                   generate(cal);        
                )
```

}
when I send first request one graph and second request another graph is generated.

**JUST GUAGE CODE**

```
function generate(cal) {

    var g1 = new JustGage({
        id : "g1",
        value : cal,
        min : 0,
        max : 100,
        title : "Protein",
        label : "",
        levelColorsGradient : false
    });
```

Ijust want to overwrite the old one instead of creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

justGauge has a function to do this called "refresh"

Change your ajax to:

```
.done(
        function(data) {
            var cal = 0;
               cal= data.cal
               g1.refresh(cal);        
            })
```

and change your justgage code so that g1 is accessible outside of your generate method:

```
var g1;
function generate(cal) {
    g1 = new JustGage({
      id : "g1",
      value : cal,
      min : 0,
      max : 100,
      title : "Protein",
      label : "",
      levelColorsGradient : false
  });
}
generate(0); //or whatever your want initial value to be
```

If you don't want any gages before the ajax call, you can instead do something like:

```
.done(
        function(data) {
            var cal = 0;
               cal= data.cal
               if(g1)
                   g1.refresh(cal);        
               else
                   generate(cal);
            })
```